# Change dropdown menu when resizing via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to change the way my dropdown menu works depending on the screen resolution. I'm doing it via jquery.

Above 1024px ul.level-2 menu shows up when cursor hovers over the button
and below 1024px it reacts on the click. Everything works good when refreshing the page on different screens but it does not work when resizing the page - $(window).resize(). When I resize browser from 1024px to lower it still reacts on hover. How Can I make it work?  Any advice would be much appreciated.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/miunik/pen/GqWYdg

**HTML**

```
<ul class="level-1">
  <li>1 level item
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1 level item
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setNav() {
    if (window.outerWidth < 1024) {
      $('.level-1 li').on({
        click: function() {
          $(this).children('.level-2').toggleClass('open');
        }
      });
    } else if (window.outerWidth > 1024) {
      $('.level-1 li').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
          $(this).children('.level-2').addClass('open');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          $(this).children('.level-2').removeClass('open');
        }
      });
    }
  }
  setNav()
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setNav();
    console.log(window.outerWidth);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you have binded the mouseenter and mouseleave function with your element.

To solve this just unbind the mouseenter and mouseleave actions from your element.

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
     $('.level-1 li').unbind( "mouseenter" );
     $('.level-1 li').unbind( "mouseleave" );
     setNav();
     console.log(window.outerWidth);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It works - with little change though, I needed to place the unbind within if statements so it works both ways (when resizing up and down).